# Config error in i3, when using the command: gaps

Tags: i3-wm

I just tried tried to add gaps to i3, just by adding

gaps inner 5px

but when I restart the config, I  get a config error for this line. Why is that?

Comment: What version or flavour of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Support for gaps configuration wasn't included in i3wm until very recently. Currently it looks like the version of i3 in the Ubuntu repo for 22.10 is only current to 4.20.1-1 and gaps support was included in the 4.22 release. It looks like the folks at i3 maintain an up to date repo https://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html, adding that repository source should enable to to update to the current version that supports gaps config.